# How to chain a list of items with an operator

Tags: python, pandas

**Scenario**

I want to filter a dataframe in pandas. It should return a dataframe with all rows that have a numeric value in a list of columns - the length of the list is arbitrary.

**Example**

```
       a   b   c
1      1   1   1
2      1   g   8
3      h   1   1
4      2   2   2
```

- If I call my function with columns [b, c], I expect rows 1, 3, and 4.
- If I call my function with columns [a], I expect rows 1, 2, and 4.

I came up with this implementation that doesn't feel pythonic but works:

```py
import typing
import pandas as pd

def filter_df(dataframe: pd.DataFrame, filter_columns: typing.List[str]) -> pd.DataFrame:

    and_connected_filters = None

    for column_name in filter_columns:

        condition: pd.Series = dataframe[column_name].str.isnumeric()

        if and_connected_filters is None:
            and_connected_filters = condition
        else:
            and_connected_filters = and_connected_filters & condition

    return dataframe[and_connected_filters]
```

**Is there a more pythonic way to chain a list of items with an operator (`&`)?**

I'm thinking of an equivalent of `",".join(...)` but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a different approach, check the status as 2D and aggregate with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
cols = ['b', 'c']

s = (df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
     .notna().all(axis=1)
    )

out = s[s].index.to_list()
```

Or, if you are sure to have strings as input:

```
cols = ['b', 'c']

s = (df[cols]
     .apply(lambda s: s.str.isnumeric())
     .all(axis=1)
    )

out = s[s].index.to_list()
```

output: `[1, 3, 4]`

Variant with [`numpy.logical_and.reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

```
import numpy as np

df.index[np.logical_and.reduce([df[c].str.isnumeric() for c in cols])].to_list()
```

output: `[1, 3, 4]`

Comment: I like this approach for *this* specific case - do you also know about the more general case of chaining items in a list using an operator like `|` or `&`?

Comment: @Maurice in this case I would use [`np.logical_and.reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html)

Comment: That's neat, thank you - sometimes you just have to know what to google for, seems like numpy has a bunch of these options :-)